# ASP.NET ListView control with a button to get all the related data up on select

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview

I am very much new to vb.net.

I am trying to display a Listview from my DB. As show below.

```
 companyID     Username

      3456        raj
      7965        king
```

But I dont how add a Button or a link as show below

```
    companyID     Username    
      3456        raj           Accept/Decline
      7965        king          Accept/Decline
```

So when the user select the Accept then I need to get the Company ID and Username and sent do some insert to another table. And if it selects the Decline just I need to delete it from DB.

I have no problem with writing insert or delete Queries But my problem is how implement Accept or Decline Button or text link and get all the details.

So can any one tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to ListView would be using GridView with template columns, try this:

In Markup create the GridView:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="MyGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlign="Center"   DataKeyNames="CompanyIDColumn" Width="100%" >

     <Columns>  

       <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyIDColumn" HeaderText="Company ID" />

       <asp:TemplateField >
           <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Label ID="UserName" Text='<%# Eval("YourUserNameColumn")%>' runat="server"/>
           </ItemTemplate>

            <HeaderTemplate>UserName</HeaderTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle Width="300px" />
            <ItemStyle Width="300px"></ItemStyle>
       </asp:TemplateField>


       <asp:TemplateField >
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="BtnDecline" CommandName="DeclineCommand" OnCommand="BtnDecline_click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CompanyIDColumn")%>' runat="server">Accept</asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>

            <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle Width="50px" />
            <ItemStyle Width="50px"/>
       </asp:TemplateField>

      </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

After you finish the gridView binding create the following BtnDecline_Click function in Code Behind:

```
 Protected Sub BtnDecline_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As CommandEventArgs)
    'The company ID in the same row in which the user clicked
    Dim CompanyID As String
    CompanyID = e.CommandArgument.ToString()

    'You can now use the company id in any opertations
 End Sub
```

Not sure if using a listView is a must for you, but this works great for me.

Comment: Hi, I have tried, but it is not working me. Can you please provide a working example.

Comment: what errors are you facing? did you bind the gridView correctly and made sure about columns names? did you change the columns names in the gridView design to match your database columns? can you give me more details about what you tried?